# Npgsql 4.0 Parameters and Null Values

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Passing a null value using Npgsql looks something like this:

```
using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into foo values (:TEST)", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("TEST", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = DBNull.Value;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Which works fine.

The new Npgsql 4.0 documentation recommends declaring parameters with a strong 
datatype, like this:

```
using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into foo values (:TEST)", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<string>("TEST", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = DBNull.Value;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

When the DBNull.Value is passed, a general exception is thrown:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

Everything still works with the new boxing-less parameters, but the new syntax seems to make sense, and we want to use it...  but how to resolve this datatype disconnect?

The example above is with a string.  I assume this will also impact numerics and dates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The new generic parameter API indeed has an issue - it should be accepting regular .NET `null` (and not `DBNull.Value`), I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2087) to track this, it will be fixed in 4.0.3.

Note that as [the documentation note](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#parameters) says, the whole point of the generic API is to avoid using the `Value` property, which is of type `object`. If you use the generic `NpgsqlParameter<int>` but assign `Value`, your int will be boxed, defeating the purpose of the API. You should be assigning to `TypedValue`, which is of type `int` and will not box. This is also why you cannot assign `DBNull.Value` to indicate a null value (it's a different .NET type).

Some notes on whether this new generic API should be used:

- If you're writing lots of value types (e.g. `int`, `DateTime`...) this will remove all boxing allocations. Whether this is going to be significant depends on your application - profile carefully.
- Generic APIs in general should always be preferred to non-generic ones when the type is known at compile-time. This allows the compiler to check type correctness early and makes your code clearer - we use `List<string>` rather than `ArrayList` as a matter of good coding even when performance isn't an issue
- The main (only?) drawback of the generic API is that it's Npgsql-specific, making your code non-portable to other database drivers (although [an issue exists](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8955) for making this (or something similar) part of ADO.NET).

Comment: I totally missed the part about `TypedValue`.  Thank you for that clarification and all of the additional information.  This is perfect.  I was hoping another advantage of this is that it would issue compile-time errors/warnings on type mismatches, so I'll find out if that's the case or not.  As far as not being portable, to me better is better, so I'd rather use it than not.  The same could be said about PostgreSQL arrays -- not very portable, yet amazing.  Speaking of amazing, NpgSql is fantastic.  Thanks for all of your contributions to a superb product.

Comment: Thanks for all the positive feedback...! Yes, since `TypedValue` is, well, typed, it will prevent some mismatch issues (strict typing is always better than weakly-typed...)

Comment: How does that work for DateTime data types where null is not a valid value? Do I just use DateTime?

Comment: The documentation note link here doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I faced with this problem, and now I don't get exceptions with it

Here how I declare parameters for Postgres functions:

```
string test;
using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into foo values (:TEST)", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TEST", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, (object)test?? DBNull.Value);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: That works for me as well, but I run into this issue when I use the unboxed version of NpgsqlParameter.  Try it with `NpgsqlParameter<string>` and I suspect you will get the same error I do.

Comment: @Hambone why you need to use it?

Comment: "Need" is a strong word.  I'm attempting to follow best practice guidelines as I understand them, in this case avoiding "useless heap allocations" and "straining the garbage collector."  http://www.npgsql.org/doc/parameters.html

Comment: @Hambone interesting. I'll learn it, in your case you can do it with no errors just don't put null values, put empty string and in function nullify value

Comment: Ugh!  I see your point, but in that case I think just going with the boxed parameter is less work and more bulletproof.  For example, what about Dates , Timestamps, numerics, JSON, XML, etc, etc.

Comment: @Hambone It can be defect of npgsql try to create issue here https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues

Comment: @Hambone don't give up =)

Comment: Just to be clear, the generic parameter API really is the recommended way - it's not more work nor less bulletproof - there's nothing about dates/timestamps or any other type that makes them more suitable for the traditional non-generic API. However, note that the perf benefits (saving allocations) will only be relevant for value types (e.g. int, DateTime) and not for strings, which are already allocated on the heap.

Comment: The only issue to be aware of with the generic parameter API is that it's Npgsql-specific - your code will be less portable to other databases (at least until this makes it into ADO.NET).