# How to Access TypedValue in Npgsql 4.0 Generic Parameters

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Follow-up on the following thread:

[Npgsql 4.0 Parameters and Null Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501878/npgsql-4-0-parameters-and-null-values)

For the new Generic Parameters that allow strongly typed values, the docs indicate that the declaration would look something like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<int>("ID", 15));
```

Which would set the `TypedValue` property on the parameter.

However, when I have multiple inserts for the same command, I can't seem to access `TypedValue` directly.  Is there a construct that would allow this?  Below is the example I'm working with, where I'm casting each parameter as its typed counterpart:

```
using (NpgsqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
{
    using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn, trans))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<Int32>("ID",
            NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<String>("TRAY_CODE", 
            NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));

        foreach (ReturnScrapDecision newRecord in NewRecords)
        {
            ((NpgsqlParameter<Int32>)cmd.Parameters[0]).TypedValue = newRecord.Id;
            ((NpgsqlParameter<String>)cmd.Parameters[1]).TypedValue = newRecord.TrayCode;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    trans.Commit();
}
```

By the way, the code above compiles, but I have no idea yet if it will run or not.  I'm still testing that.

I can set `Value` fine:

```
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = newRecord.Id;
```

But I cannot do this without casting:

```
cmd.Parameters[0].TypedValue = newRecord.Id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NpgsqlCommand.Parameters` is an `IList<NpgsqlParameter>` - of the non-generic kind. So when you do `cmd.Parameters[0]` you're getting back a classic `NpgsqlParameter` and not `NpgsqlParameter<T>`.

You can use downcasting:

```
((NpgsqlParameter<int>)cmd.Parameters[0]).TypedValue = newRecord.Id;
```

Or better yet, just use an initializer when you allocate the parameter:

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<Int32>("ID", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer) { TypedValue = newRecord.Id });
```

Comment: Thanks, as always...  the second method works when it's a single value, but in my example I am compiling once, executing many times with multiple values.  In that case, instantiating the parameter over and over doesn't seem to make sense.  Do you think it would be possible to add a `TypedParameters` property to the `NpgsqlCommand` class that accesses the typed variants?

Answer (score 0):

(Adding an answer since I cannot comment...)

The problem with a `TypedParameters` property is that you end up with a collection of mixed types and would still need to cast them.

How about a solution like this?

```
using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn, trans))
{
    var idParam = new NpgsqlParameter<Int32>("ID", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(idParam);
    var trayCodeParam = new NpgsqlParameter<String>("TRAY_CODE", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(trayCodeParam);

    foreach (ReturnScrapDecision newRecord in NewRecords)
    {
        idParam.TypedValue = newRecord.Id;
        trayCodeParam.TypedValue = newRecord.TrayCode;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```