# Difference Between Using `NpgsqlParameter<T>` and `AddWithValue` with `NpgsqlDbType`

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, strong-typing

The [Npgsql documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#strongly-typed-parameters) states that using `NpgsqlParameter<T>` is better because it is strongly-typed and doesn't strain the garbage collector with useless heap allocations caused by boxing value types.

I have the below two commands that declare the data type to use for a specific parameter:

***Not Using `NpgsqlParameter<T>`:***

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, 123);
```

***Using `NpgsqlParameter<T>`:***

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<Int32>("id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer) { TypedValue = 123 });
```

My question is, is the first command equivalent to the second (won't box the `int` value) or should I use the second one instead?

I think the first just tells Npgsql what data type to use but will still box the `int`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "AddWithValue is bad" is about *SQLServer*. MySQL [actively promote its use](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/) - please give some detail on why AddWithValue is problematic for PG, otherwise those links are just irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After careful consideration of the input we've received from the community, we have decided to go with `NpgsqlParameter<T>` with an explicit `NpgsqlDbType`.

While we agree that performance hits are indeed very difficult to notice with both options, the explicitness of declaring what you're passing and what you want it to be converted to has convinced us to go with the slightly more verbose option.

Many thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 2):

This is not really intended as an answer, as I believe Mr. Harvey has sufficiently done that, but it's longer than I can put in a comment and wouldn't have the formatting...  so apologies in advance.

First of all, please see feedback from one of the authors of Npgsql on when the generic API should be used:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51568458/1278553

Also, I didn't see it in this post, but I recall a comment from him as well that indicated one of the drawbacks to the new API is that it is not portable to other ADO.net adapters, meaning if you change your datasource to Oracle, expect this to NOT work.

Now on to my hot sports opinion...  I've seen, understand and agree with the rationale for not using `AddWithValue`.  That said, I'll be the first to admit I use it.  The reason is it usually works, and I think the method name is very transparent as to what it is accomplishing.

The two cases where I strictly avoid it are:

- Declare once, assign many, as within a transaction where you are doing multiple inserts, updates (or upserts)
- Dates.  Since PostreSQL has a date and a timestamp but .NET has only System.Datetime, `AddWithValue` seems to assume you mean System.DateTime -> timestamp, which will cause your program to puke.  In this case, AddWithValue saves you little, as you need to re-declare the datatype as a date

It does work for array datatypes, though, which is pretty fantastic.

So, you could do this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("FOO", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = myArray;
```

or you can do:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FOO", myArray);
```

And it works perfectly...  I really love PostgreSQL and NpgSql.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of NpgsqlParameter<T> over AddWithValue is avoiding boxing, since AddWithValue accepts an object. That means that any time you pass a value type (int, double) to AddWithValue, you're incurring a needless heap allocation.

As for the rest of it... I'm not aware of any other advantages that relate to type inference and performance, as per the links posted above. NpgsqlParameter<T> accepts a strongly-typed .NET type, but Npgsql must still infer a *PostgreSQL* type from it. For example, .NET `string` can be mapped to PostgreSQL `text`, but also `varchar` or `jsonb`. In fact, the type inference happening internally is identical whether the .NET type is specificied generically with NpgsqlParameter<T>, or simply by looking at the type of the object passed to AddWithValue. If you want to avoid inference, you'll have to specify an NpgsqlDbType - including with NpgsqlParameter<T>.

Note also that I'm not aware of significant or common *performance* issues related to bad inference (as implied in some of the SQL Server links). In most cases the query will simply fail, because the inferred type is somehow incompatible - but it's pretty rare for it to run slowly.